# Rails: Cannot get tabs to work with and kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tabs, kaminari

I have two tabs at the profile page: tab 1) my recipes, tab 2) my favorites.

Kaminari pagination works just fine when I go to the index page for recipes. However the pagination does not work properly at the profile page. When I click on next it does show me the next page, but the pagination bar disappears. So I cannot go back, unless I refresh the page.

Who can help me? Thank you in advance.

**Profile controller:**

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @recipes = current_user.recipes.order("name").page(params[:recipes_page]).per(3)
    @favorites = current_user.favorites.order("name").page(params[:favorites_page]).per(3)
  end
end
```

**Kaminari:**

```
<% if @recipes.present? %>
      <div class="apple_pagination" id="paginator-my-recipes">
        <%= paginate @recipes, :remote => true, :param_name => :recipes_page %>
      </div>
<% end %>
```

**app/views/profiles/show.html.erb:**

```
<div class="container is-small sand-color">
    <div class="tabs">
      <div class="your-recipes-btn">
        <a class= "tab active" data-target= "#your-recipes">
          <h4>Your recipes</h4>
        </a>
      </div>

      <div class="your-favorites-btn">
        <a class= "tab" data-target= "#your-favo">
          <h4>Favorites</h4>
        </a>
      </div>

    </div>
</div>

<div class="tab-content" id="your-recipes">
  <div class="container is-small sand-color">
    <% if @recipes.present? %>
     <%= render @recipes %>
    <% else %>
     <h4 class="text-center">Create your own recipes</h4>
    <% end %>
  </div>
    <% if @recipes.present? %>
      <div class="apple_pagination" id="paginator-my-recipes">
        <%= paginate @recipes, :remote => true, :param_name => :recipes_page %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>

<div class="tab-content hidden" id="your-favo">
  <div class="container is-small sand-color">
    <% if @favorites.present? %>
      <%= render @favorites %>
    <% else %>
      <h4 class="text-center">You don't have any recipes</h4>
    <% end %>
  </div>
    <% if @favorites.present? %>
      <div class="apple_pagination" id="paginator-my-favo">
        <%= paginate @favorites, :remote => true, :param_name => :favorites_page %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**app/views/profiles/_favorites.html.erb**

```
 <div class="product">
    <div class='product-upvote'>
      <div class="product-arrow"></div>
      <div class='product-count'>95</div>
    </div>
    <% if recipe.photo != nil %>
    <%= cl_image_tag recipe.photo, height: 100, width: 150, crop: :fill, class: "product-image hidden-xs" %>
    <% else %>
    <% end %>
    <div class='product-body'>
      <%= link_to recipe_path(recipe) do %>
      <h4><%= recipe.name  %></h4>
      <% end %>
      <div class="summary dont-break-out">
        <p><%= recipe.summary %></p>
      </div>

      <div class="recipes-info">
        <div class="recipes-kitchen">
          <p>Gang</p>
          <h5> <%= recipe.course %> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="recipes-kitchen">
          <p>Keuken</p>
          <h5> <%= recipe.kitchen %> </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="cooking-time">
          <p>Kooktijd</p>
          <h5><%= recipe.cooking_time %> min</h5>
        </div>

        <div class="created">
          <p>Geplaatst op</p>
          <h5><%= recipe.created_at.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %> </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**app/views/profiles/show.js.erb:**

```
$('#your-recipes').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@recipes) %>');
$('#paginator-my-recipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@recipes, :remote => true).to_s) %>');

$('#your-favo').html('<%= escape_javascript render(@favorites) %>');
$('#paginator-my-favo').html('<%= escape_javascript(paginate(@favorites, :remote => true).to_s) %>');
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your profile & index page views and action?

Comment: @oreoluwa I will update the question.